# What is the meaning of "do a barrel roll"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

At work I heard in the middle of a conversation someone saying "well, `do a barrel roll` in that case", like if nothing more could be done.

What would it mean in the context of business?

Comment: [It's from a video game called Starfox. Whenever you were in trouble this useless character would tell you to do a barrel roll, which didn't help you in the slightest. It's a term people say to let you know that they're giving you useless information that won't help you at all.](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100314151148AAlF27B) But I had to search on Google to find that - hardly anyone would understand it, since it's *not* an "established idiomatic usage" by any reasonable standard. It's certainly not something you'd expect the average articulate *businessman* to use.

Comment: @FumbleFingers : again, this is an answer not a comment. Why aren't you posting as an answer so that others can vote on it and the OP can accept it?

Comment: Have a look at the wikipedia entry for the usual meaning of [barrel roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_roll). This might help with figurative uses of the term.

Comment: @sammy gerbil: I've closevoted because I don't think there's any point in having questions like this formally answered on ELL. It's nowhere near "mainstream English", and for all I know it no longer has whatever currency it might have once had (that Yahoo answer is over 7 years old).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Very good find indeed! Digging further made me discover another forgotten sentence: [Kilroy was here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilroy_was_here) "meanstream" English for sure, but still in the OED.

Comment: @mins: I don't think there's any *meaning* to *Kilroy was here*, so if you heard it in conversation (unlikely, imho) you'd have to assume some contextualized meaning. Nevertheless, it's familiar to many native speakers, and it's now lasted for over 70 years. I also found [The phrase “do a barrel roll” comes from the sequel Star Fox 64 released on July 1st, 1997, in which the character Peppy Hare orders you to “Do a barrel roll!” while approaching 4 stationary turrets firing lasers.](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/do-a-barrel-roll), but I can't see that it really caught on.

Comment: @sammygerbil Some people get into a bad habit. Even I do at times. But I think [it is best practice not to write an answer in a comment](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/if-you-dont-want-to-write-an-answer-which-is-better-write-an-answer-in-a-comm)

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the wikipedia article suggested by Lawrence, doing a [barrel roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_roll) seems to mean that you should "do something different" and "change your perspective," setting the problem aside for while and doing something unrelated to it before coming back to it. This is common advice if you are having a mental block.

However, my interpretation does not quite agree with the origins of the phrase in a Nintendo 64 game, as found by FumbleFingers in the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Do+a+barrel+roll). There the phrase is described as being used as **a panacea for all problems** - perhaps the equivalent of the IT fix-all "Have you tried turning it off and back on again".